# Iterating over a multilevel array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have an array of values that can be cycled through using the next/prev buttons:

Example:

```
var sav = [
    "first item",
    "second item",
    "third item"
];

var box = document.getElementById('box');

var i = -1;

function next() {
    i = i >= sav.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;
    box.innerHTML = sav[i];
}

function prev() {
    i = i > 0 ? i - 1 : sav.length - 1;
    box.innerHTML = sav[i];
}

<a href="#" onclick="prev()">Previous</a>
<div id="box"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="next()">Next</a>
```

Tell me please how to iterate over if the array is multidimensional?

I managed to make an example based on a one-dimensional array, but it does not work in the case of a multidimensional one

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any multidimensional arrays in your code shown..

Comment: Please show your multidimensional array and explain how you would like to iterate and cycle it. Just `.flat()`tening it?

Answer (score 1):

The `next()` and `prev()` functions just need a little logic to cycle two, dependent variables. The snippet below explains further:

```js
var sav = [
    ["0-a", "0-b", "0-c"],
    ["1-a", "1-b", "1-c"],
    ["2-a", "2-b", "2-c"],
];

const box = document.getElementById('box');
let row = 0, col = 0;
box.innerHTML = sav[row][col];

function next() {
    if (col === sav[row].length-1) {
      // if the col is at its limit, reset...
      col = 0;
      // ...and advance the row. if we're at its limit, reset it, too
      row = row === sav.length-1 ? 0 : row+1;
    } else { // otherwise, just advance the col
      col = col+1
    }
    box.innerHTML = sav[row][col]
}

function prev() {
    // same as above, except 0 is the limit, and we subtract to "advance"
    if (col === 0) {
      col = sav[row].length-1;
      row = row === 0 ? sav.length-1 : row-1;
    } else {
      col = col-1
    }
    box.innerHTML = sav[row][col]
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="prev()">Previous</a>
<div id="box"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="next()">Next</a>
```